# Skim not opening or updating on build with Sublime Text 4 and LaTeXTools on Mac

Tags: preview, latextools

I am building a pdf from ST4 with LaTeXTools. The build is fine. ST4's console's shows this after the build:

> Welcome to thread Thread-11 Running "latexmk -cd -f -pdf
> -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 FileName.tex" Finished normally 0 False False True Jump to:  12 794 <class
> '_latextools_skim_viewer.SkimViewer'> Running
> "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -r 13
> /Users/.../FileName.pdf
> /Users/.../FileName.tex"

So it seems ST4 is calling Skim. Yet nothing opens. The 'open -a Skim.app' from the Terminal works and Skim does if called like that.

If I open the pdf file 'manually' from Skim, the reverse sync with ST4 is working.

I have  "keep_focus":false in my settings.

Finally I am running ST4 (build 4126) on macOS Monterey. If I run the same build of ST4 on a macOS Big Sur I do NOT have this problem.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: Do You have Sumatra?

Comment: The above solution by Alessandro Baccarini works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It is a Skim issue. Updating to the [test version of Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/Skim.zip) did the trick for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. Tried it but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Following Alessandro Baccarini's comment, I did this and it worked:

Go to Skim's pageweb https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/ and download the most recent version 1.6.8, released on 2022-01-06. Install it, move it to Applications (where current skim is) and replace the old version.